# django pagination returns nothing

Tags: django

i'm not sure what went wrong here. spent hours trying to figure out. when run the program i can see list of objects displayed but none of pagination.html information is displayed.

**views.py**

```
def post_list(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    p = Paginator(post_list, 2)
    page_num = request.GET.get('page',1)
    posts = p.page(page_num)   
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {"posts":posts})
```

**list.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block title %} My Post{% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
            {% for post in posts %}
                <ol>
                    {{post.title}} by {{post.author}} published= {{post.status}}  slug==> {{post.slug}}
                    <span><a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">details</a></span> 
                </ol>
            {% endfor %}
            {% include "directory/pagination.html" with pages=posts %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**pagination.html**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if pages.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ pages.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ pages.number }} of {{ pages.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if pages.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ pages.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ pages.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some changes you want to make

**views.py**

```py
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from .models import Post


def post_list(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    p = Paginator(post_list, 2)
    page_num = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    posts = p.get_page(page_num)
    return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {"posts": posts})
```

`p.get_page()` is used instead of `p.page()` because `get_page()` automatically handles invalid page numbers for you.

**list.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %} My Posts {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <ol>
        {% for post in posts %}
            <li>
                {{ post.title }} by {{ post.author }} (status: {{ post.status }}) - Slug: {{ post.slug }}
                <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">details</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
    {% include "blog/pagination.html" with pages=posts %}
{% endblock %}
```

your `<ol>` tag is placed inside the loop to fix it place your `<ol>` tag outside the loop like above.

and the rest of the code looks fine. but if you're still facing the error double check your correct using the `{%include%}` tag in the template.

Comment: Django provide a few classes to paginate your data [Paginator class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/paginator/#paginator-class) give it a try

Comment: everything works fine except pagination.html is not displaying at all. thanks for your help